# Surface brightness of transparent vs opaque galaxies

Tags: galaxy, surface, brightness

When describing surface brightness of galaxies, I would imagine that in some wavelengths some galaxies are mostly transparent and in other wavelengths some are somewhat opaque (for example galaxies can have little or lots of dust, spirals can be side-on or face-on, and some wavelengths will be obscured and some not). In other words, in some cases the surface brightness is correlated with the amount of visible matter in the galaxy, while in other cases it is correlated only with the "visible surface" of the galaxy.

So my question is: in studies in which surface brightness is for example correlated with the visible mass of galaxies, are only certain types of galaxies and certain wavelengths of light used? Or are correlations established only between the "visible surface" of galaxies and their mass -- i.e. is the term "surface brightness" doing double duty in both describing the brightness across angular surface of the celestial sphere while also describing the literal surface brightness?